# Передача массива структур в С++

Tags: c++

```
void Move(struct Rabbit *rabbit) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        coord1.X = rabbit[i].X;
        coord1.Y = rabbit[i].Y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, coord1);
        cout <<  " ";
    }
}
```

В строках

```
        coord1.X = rabbit[i].X; 
        coord1.Y = rabbit[i].Y;
```

выводит ошибку:

> выражение должно представлять указатель на полный тип объекта

Comment: coord1.X = rabbit[i].X;
  coord1.Y = rabbit[i].Y;  здесь выводит ошибку "выражение должно представлять указатель на полный тип объекта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, у вас до этого кода нет полного объявления типа `Rabbit` - и компилятор до функции `Move` встречал только что-то вроде

```
struct Rabbit;
```

Т.е. он знает, что такой тип есть, но что у него внутри - не знает, а в данный момент это уже важно.

Измените код так, чтобы полное объявление `Rabbit` было доступно для компилятора к этому моменту.